# getimagesize is not working on linux server

Tags: php, getimagesize

This code returning false on my hosting server, but not on my localhost

```
if(getimagesize($photo_tmp_name)) {
 ....
} else {
  echo 'error getimage size'; // i did this to check only
}
```

Note: $photo_tmp_name is valid, its just that I get `getimagesize` error.

Comment: What is value of the `$photo_tmp_name`? Relative or absolute path of the image, is it really correct path?

Comment: There must be some error reported, turn on error reporting, so that you can get some insight

Comment: @PetrHejda, that is a tmp name `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: @Stacklearner nothing I check it everytime i changed something